# System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException in wcf service

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, wcf, iis

I am trying to call my WCF service through a Flex application. I'm getting the System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException. I have Integrated Windows Auth switched to on, anonymous access off, and I've set impersonate to false in my web.config. The project and virtual dir are named the same too.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <webHttpBinding>
>     <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding">
>       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
>         <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>   </webHttpBinding>
> </bindings>
> ```

This needed to be added to the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The AspNetCompatibilityRequirements omission is another posible cause
What you need to do is make sure your service has this.

```
[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false,
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall),
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IService
```

Comment: Just to clarify it depends only on this part [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

Answer (score 0):

at IIS, Authentication, enable the Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation