# How to add the binding to the Config file of WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am writing a WCF application for Accepting a file from android using POST and it throws a System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivation exception, I understood what is to be done from the from the link :-

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException in wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025700/system-servicemodel-serviceactivationexception-in-wcf-service)

The following is the Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
            <service name="WcfImageUpload.Service1"
                     behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://somesite.com:5555/Service1/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint name="Service1"
                          address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfImageUpload.IService1" 
                          behaviorConfiguration="web"/>

                <endpoint name="LoginServiceMex"
                          address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I need to add bindings

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Where should I add that, I am a newbie in .NET and WCF.

Comment: Try ths link                                http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx

Comment: Add it to your config, just **after** the `</behaviors>` element

Answer (score 1):

You can place  as like below....

> ```
> <system.serviceModel>
>   <services>
>    <service  name="MyService">
>   <endpoint address="http://localhost/IISHostedService/MyService.svc" 
>   binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="wshttpbind" contract="IMyService">
>   <identity>
>   <dns value="localhost"/>
>   </identity>
>   </endpoint>
>   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
>     </service>
>   </services>
>   <bindings>
>       <webHttpBinding>
>          <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding">
>            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
>              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
>            </security>
>          </binding>
>       </webHttpBinding>
>    </bindings>
>
> </system.serviceModel>
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the binding in the web.config of the WCF service inside the `<system.ServiceModel>` tag.

You have multiple bindings supported by WCF, like basic http binding, Web HttpBinding, wsHttpBinding etc.

If you are going to access the service like a asmx service, use BasicHttpBinding which uses SOAP.

If you want your WCF to be RESTful , then use WebHttpBinding and configure the behaviour accordingly. there are other bindings like wsHttpBindlings which are more secure.